# How to add a second DSL Connection to my network

Tags: dsl, load-balance

We have vdsl 50 internet connection that fails from time to time. Therefore we planned to order a second line that is completly different e.g. cable modem based.

What is the best way to integrate that into the network?

Should we just use 2 gateways or should we integrate a reverse proxy or are there load balancer out there?

Answer (score 0):

Get a decent router that allows "Uplink Balancing" and "Multipath Rules" (Sophos) or "Smart Link Backup" (Cisco). I'm sorry that I cannot give you a technically correct name. To get a concept of the idea, you could check a video by Sophos: https://vimeo.com/97463769

Basically with the Sophos you have the advantage, that you have a failover/standby interface, but you can also use the Multipath Rules to route certain traffic (HTTP/SMTP/...) over specific WAN links.

Excuse the product-oriented explanation, but I really don't know if all that stuff has a correct technical name :(

Comment: A link balancer is another option https://www.barracuda.com/products/linkbalancer. Also some firewalls can handle the additional ISP intelligently.

Comment: We are testing ipfire at the moment - perhaps we could do it with that?